# Julia on Windows. How to pass command line options to an executable file

Tags: julia

I wish to call an executable file from Julia via `Base.run` [(documented here)](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v0.7.0/manual/running-external-programs/#Running-External-Programs-1) and pass command line options to that executable, but I can't figure out how to do that. In my specific example the executable is [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) and the [command line options](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Command_Line_Switches) are

```
-alwaysOnTop -nosession
```

This example code works, but doesn't pass the command line options:

```
function open_file_in_notepadpp()
    exepath =   "C:/Program Files (x86)/notepad++/notepad++.exe"   #Default location on 64 bit Windows
    command_line_options = "-alwaysOnTop -nosession "
    filetoopen = "c:/temp/foo.txt"
    Base.run(`$exepath $filetoopen`, wait = false)   
end
```

I've tried incorporating `command_line_options` a fair number of ways using backticks, double quotes etc. to no avail, so for example neither of the lines below work:

```
Base.run(`$exepath $filetoopen`, `$command_line_options`,wait = false)
Base.run(`$exepath $command_line_options $filetoopen`,wait = false)
```

In the Windows Command Prompt the following works correctly:

```
"C:/Program Files (x86)/notepad++/notepad++.exe" -alwaysOnTop -nosession "c:/temp/foo.txt"
```

Could someone explain what I'm missing?

Comment: Basically you want to invoke npp from julia?

Comment: Why dont you put command line option into run()?

Comment: I tried `Base.run(`$exepath $filetoopen`, `$command_line_options`,wait = false)` but get `ERROR: MethodError: no method matching spawn_opts_swallow(::Cmd)`

Comment: Sorry, that comment got garbled by the conflict between using backticks to encapsulate a command in Julia and using backticks to indicate code in the markup used here on stack overflow...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you substitute a string that contains spaces to a command it will get quoted. Hence, your command line arguments will be quoted and you get

```
julia> `$exepath $filetoopen $command_line_options`
`'C:/Program Files (x86)/notepad++/notepad++.exe' c:/temp/foo.txt '-alwaysOnTop -nosession '`
```

I guess what you really need is

```
julia> command_line_options = ["-alwaysOnTop", "-nosession"]
2-element Array{String,1}:
 "-alwaysOnTop"
 "-nosession"

julia> `$exepath $filetoopen $command_line_options`
`'C:/Program Files (x86)/notepad++/notepad++.exe' c:/temp/foo.txt -alwaysOnTop -nosession`
```

Running the latter with `run` should work. Unfortunately I can't test it on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

crstnbr's answer was correct, but he was unable to test on his machine. Here is the corrected code:

```
function open_file_in_notepadpp()
    exepath =   "C:/Program Files (x86)/notepad++/notepad++.exe"   #Location if one follows the defaults in the notepad++ installer on 64 bit Wndows
    command_line_options = ["-alwaysOnTop", "-nosession"]          #Use an array to prevent the options being quoted 
    filetoopen = "c:/temp/foo.txt"

    Base.run(`$exepath $filetoopen $command_line_options`,wait = false)

end
```